# Google can not see my site

Tags: google-search

when I type my domain name http://www.mcqtoday.com in google it shows some other site. I have submitted the sitemap to google web master, it says 2 page is indexed, but does not show in search result. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably, however, Google states at the very top of the search results: "Showing results for mqtoday.com - Search instead for mcqtoday.com"? Unfortunately (for you) Google thinks that people are more likely to want to be searching for "mqtoday.com" than "mcqtoday.com" and perhaps sees "mcqtoday.com" as a typo. "mqtoday.com" is far more established and "mcqtoday.com" is previously unheard of and very closely spelled. However, users are unlikely to be searching on your domain name - concentrate on your content and keywords, as guisasso suggests.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 pages indexed, google "sees" your website.

There are many reasons why that other website shows up before yours on google. Mainly relevancy.

That domain is older and more relevant. Has more links pointing to it, and your website has almost the exact same name, it only differs by one letter.

Build up on good content and links, and you shall have better results.

If the website is brand new, and you don't want google to display "did you mean", using a different domain name may be an option.

Cheers!